# Reindexing with hibernate/HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, hql, reindex

We are trying to reindex our database through hibernate by using session.createQuery and executeUpdate. For some reason this is simply just not working. This all is done in a job that has a timer to do this every week at a certain time.

```
  session().createQuery("ALTER INDEX indexName ON tableName REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (     PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, ONLINE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF )").executeUpdate();
```

Is executeUpdate() the correct thing to be using? Or are there other things that are wrong with this code etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a DB function from Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902514/calling-a-db-function-from-hibernate) . Dup by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

*Hibernate* Query Language does not support arbitrary, vendor-specific SQL.

You can [execute native queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#querysql-creating) with `Session.createSQLQuery()`, but I would probably use `Session.doWork()` and raw JDBC.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of/thinking but had trouble finding documentation. Thanks, I'll read up on it and give it a try.