# Calling a DB function from Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, indexing, hql

I am trying to build a job that reindexes our DB every Friday. We are using hibernate and everything I have tried so far has failed. Is there a way to execute SQL managament commands using hibernate? Such as:

```
    Session session = helper.getSession();
    session.createQuery("DBCCREINDEX(User)").executeUpdate();
```

Or is there a better way to reindex within Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples referenced below are for Oracle PL/SQL but conceptually it's the same for other databases. By "build a job" and "execute SQL managament commands" I assume you'll have some sort of function stored in the database that you need to call.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943733/131929 has a lengthy explanation but it boils down to

```
CallableStatement statement = session.connection().prepareCall(
        "{ ? = call name_of_your_function(?) }");
```

which allows you to work directly with a `Connection` and a `PreparedStatement`/`CallableStatement`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1703398/131929 is essentially the same but it makes use of `Session#doWork`

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
  public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call name_of_your_function(?) }");
```

Note that in both examples it was required to process the function's return value in the Java code which may or may not be the case with you.

Comment: We ended up doing something along these lines.

Comment: Is there a difference between using a CallableStatement and just using PreparedStatement like the solution I provided? (is one more correct?)

Comment: "We ended up doing something along these lines" - oh, really? Then it'd have been nice if you at least upvoted, if not accepted, this answer. In fact, using `CallableStatement` as in the example is _possibly_ (really don't know) more "correct" than your solution as `CallableStatement` is intended to be used to call stored procedures/functions. Try Google for "CallableStatement vs. PreparedStatement" e.g. [this](http://crunchify.com/what-are-the-difference-between-jdbcs-statement-preparedstatement-and-callablestatement/), not enough room here for more.

Answer (score 0):

`Session.createQuery()` expects a HQL query. If you want to execute SQL, use [`Session.createSQLQuery()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: We ended up trying this and I believe the problem was that we were calling a stored procedure that did not return anything. createSQLQuery() uses a method that returns a resultSet but our query did not return anything (just does an action ... reindexes). So it was incorrect for our implementation. Thanks for the answer, however.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up working our way after many errors up to the solution below. The prepared statement is a stored procedure to reindex created in MSSQL SSMS.

```
    private void reindex() {
        Session session = helper.getSession();
        PreparedStatement ps;
        session.doWork(new Work() {
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("reindexTable");
            ps.execute();
        }
    });
}
```

This seems to have given the desired result and executes...however we just have to solve a timeout issue now.

Comment: "solve a timeout issue now" - yes, I can imagine. If the called procedure takes "long" (whatever that means) to complete, you'll want to use `setQueryTimeout` on the statement and run the whole thing in its own worker thread.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code  -

```
private void reindex() {
    Session session = helper.getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps;
        session.doWork(new Work() {
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("reindexTable");
            ps.execute();
        }
    });
}
```